# javascript array find longest and ID first if more than on present

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and want to

1. find the longest element (most characters in string)
2. find if more than one element ties for most and
3. if there is a tie, return the first of the array.

In the code I have below, andrew and johnny would tie for most but I'd want andrew to return for the function. I was able to first ID the longest if no tie, but now incorporated the second FOR. I know the issue is in my second FOR but I don't know how to solve. Any help is appreciated. Thanks,

```
var a = ["kevin", "david", "matt", "ben", "andrew", 'johnny']

var lgth = 0;
var longest;
var sortedArray;

function longestFunc(){
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i].length>lgth){
            lgth = a[i].length;
            longest = a[i];
        }
    }
    for(var j = 0; j<a.length; j++){
      if(a[j] != longest && a[j].length = longest.length){
        longest = a[j];
    }
  }
    return longest;
}
longestFunc(a);
```

Comment: By ID do you mean `key`?

Comment: No, sorry I mean I can return the element with the longest string. I can't yet pull the first instance on the array which is part of the tie.

Comment: The second `for` loop is doing exactly the thing that you don't want to do. When the first loop finds "andrew", the second switches the longest to "johnny".  The way to fix that is to remove the second loop entirely, as you don't want it (apparently).

Comment: You only need one loop. You have `a[j].length = longest.length`, I think you meant `==` but perhaps you need `a[j].length > longest.length`.

Comment: Thanks for helping, removing will always return the first instance of the tie, here "andrew"(which I just realized). The reason I included the second loop is to say if any element which isn't "andrew" has the same length as "andrew", confirm there is a tie. I have 2 questions: 1. I'm wondering if its possible to do this second loop and how (just for my own knowledge) and 2. Apparently all I really need is to confirm if there is a tie (in this case there is), so I'm trying to find out the best way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "confirm there is a tie"? What would you expect the return value of the function to be if there *is* a tie?

Answer (score 3):

Can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do this

```js
var a = ["kevin", "david", "matt", "ben", "andrew", 'johnny'];

var results = a.reduce(function(res, curr) {
  if (curr.length > res[0].length) {
    // when new longest found, reset accumulator
    res = [curr, 1];
  } else if (curr.length === res[0].length) {
    //increment accumulator for other matching lengths
    res[1] ++;
  }
  return res;
}, ['', 1]);

document.write('longest is ' + results[0] + ' , tie count = ' + results[1])
```

Comment: This is great, but I think could look like confusing magic to some beginners. You might want to explain that ternary operator and how reduce works.

Comment: @BenjaminGolder the link to the documentation explains how it works

Comment: @charlietfl no idea it could be done in such a short way +1.

Comment: Great thanks, I'll read up on this (definitely am a beginner). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly the below code is what you want.

Try this,

```
var names = ["Script47", "Bob", "Jimmy", "Christopher"];

function findLongest(a) 
{
    var lastLongest = a[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].length > lastLongest.length)
            lastLongest = a[i];
    }
    return lastLongest;
}

console.log(findLongest(names));
```

**Output**

`Christopher`

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/mj2rdrm5/

**Edit 1:**

To get the length you'd do the following.

```
var longest = findLongest(names);
var length = longest.length;
```

Comment: This is what I had initially, before the second FOR statement. It does identify the longest, but I'm still needing a way to state "there is a tie" and be able to return the first, second or third name in the array which is part of the tie.

Comment: @KM617 I thought that logic was a bit flawed, if you return the first one out of an array, you still wouldn't know it was a tie as it would be returning a string, however: http://jsfiddle.net/h94n4d1g/

Comment: this looks like a better way to do what I tried (return first instance of largest string). How would this tell you a tie exists though?

Comment: @KM617 if you wanted to do that why not return an array containing all the possible values.

Comment: Are you saying to push all elements which "tie" to an array? That would work. I don't know how to actually write this but if I can find a way that will work.

Comment: @KM617 try this: http://jsfiddle.net/h94n4d1g/1/. It returns an array, then you'd loop to display values, open the console to see them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function longestFunc(a){
        var longest = '';
        for(var key in a) {
          if(a[key].length > longest.length){
            longest = a[key];
          }
        }
        return longest;
    }
```

This should work for you.